# how do you specify an AlphaChannelType arguments to alpha() in ruby imagemagick (magick)

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm trying to use the img.alpha(SOMETHING) command in the ruby magick library (in a custom manipulate routine used by carrierwave).

alpha() expects an argument of Magick::AlphaChannelType but I cannot find any doucmentaiton on how to specify such an argument, or what options are available.

The docs say the argument shoudl be:

> One of the following values of the AlphaChannelType enumeration:
>
> ActivateAlphaChannel Enable the images use of transparency. If
>   transparency data did not exist, allocate the data and set to opaque.
>   If the image previously had transparency data, the data is again
>   enable as it was when turned off. The transparency data is not changed
>   or modified in any way.
>   ...

But do not give any examples of how to actually specify one of the 10 possible argument values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlphaChannelTypes that [`alpha`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#alpha) wants are constants within `Magick` so you want to use `Magick::ActivateAlphaChannel`, `Magick::BackgroundAlphaChannel`, ...:

```
img.alpha(Magick::ActivateAlphaChannel)
```

I don't my way around CarrierWave but I'd guess it just wants to see one of the `Magick::` constants somewhere.